# Understanding first order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to understand first order (homogenous) linear differential equations. Those are the most basic ones.

The method being used to solve the differential equations is 
based on the separation of variables.

> $$\begin{align}
> y'_h(t)-a(t)y_h(t)&=0\\
> \frac{y'_h(t)}{y_h(t)}&=a(t)\\
> \int{\frac{\mathrm dy_h(t)}{y_h(t)}}&=\int a_h(t)\,\mathrm dt\\
> \color{blue}{\ln\left|y_h(t)\right|+c^{te}}&=\smallint a(t)\,\mathrm dt\\
> \left|y_h(t)\right|&=e^{\smallint a(t)\,\mathrm dt+c^{the}}\\
> y_h(t)&=\pm\left(e^{\smallint a(t)\,\mathrm dt}.e^{c^{te}}\right)\\
> &=Ke^{\smallint a(t)\,\mathrm dt}
> \end{align}$$

But I don't understand why a natural logarithm, e-number and an absolute value are needed to solve this basic equation on the picture.

Comment: what is $\ln x$ for $x<0$ assuming you are dealing with real solutions? and why do you have the log turn up? its a pretty nice function given the functions out there.

Comment: Your goal is to find an expression of $y(t)$ but you are given an equation containing $y^{'}(t)$ and $y(t)$ itself. Therefore it is logical to conclude that an integral will be used to get rid of the first derivative and in this case the solution to the integral gave $ln|y(t)|$. Then you have to get rid of the $ln$ so you take $exp$ on both sides and voila.

Comment: @kevin001 Oh ok, so the result in this case was ln x ("coincidence"). But ln|y(t)| is not a standard part of the algorithm to solve differential equations? And they did take the exp of the left part, but didn't write it: they immediately jumped to the next step and wrote the solution.